# MongoDB Query Subdocuments by field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
"vmwVmCpus": {
"name": "vmwVmCpus", 
"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.2.1.1.9", 
"nodetype": "column", 
"class": "objecttype", 
"syntax":
  {
  "type": "Integer32", 
  "class": "type"
   }, 
"maxaccess": "read-only", 
"status": "current"}
```

Returns the correct result

```
db.collectionName.find({ "vmwVmCpus.oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.2.1.1.9" });
```

I need to be able to query for "1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.2.1.1.9" and return a result. 
I tried the following but it did not work.

```
db.collectionName.find(
  {"oid" : {$regex :/.*1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.6876\.4\.1\.0\.306.*/i}}
 );
```

Comment: When performing a query I only know have the data of "1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.2.1.1.9". So I am not able to do the dot notation in the query.

Comment: Can you update your OP to include the correct value you’re trying to find. Or give an example of the data so I can show you the correct formst

Comment: The field oid is located is several documents and sub documents. I need to execute a query where I input the value of the field oid and return that document. For example in SQL I would use something like Select * from collectionName where oid = '1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.2.1.1.9'

Comment: Ok, but in you OP you mention that that query works. I need to understand where you need the range in regex. The query your saying doesn’t work, where is the data changing? It might be easier to post multiple values so people can see where in your regex you need to expand your match.

Comment: I guess my question boils down to sis there a way to query for a string that is stored any where in the collection without using the dot notation (vmwVmCpus.oid)?

Comment: That only seems to work if the oid field is top document but in my case the oid field is in sub documents. I executed your query but no results.

Comment: The simple answer is you need to use the .dot in order to access embedded docs. Any reason why they need to be embedded. I thought you were trying to regex on an I.P range :-) I’ve removed my answer as it’s irrelevant

Comment: In my situation I only have the value of the oid field and needing to do a lookup by the value without knowing the dot.notation in the schema.

Comment: Is the sub doc name field always the same as the parent doc id

Comment: The field names will be different per row.